# Dar formato de fecha a un Entry en Python

Tags: python, tkinter, formato

Buenas tardes comunidad...

Soy algo novato en Python. Me encuentro practicando el código y se me surgió una inquietud al momento de ingresar una fecha en un Entry.

El control `Entry` puede dar formato de fechas o el que se le especifique?

Por ejemplo, si quiero ingresar una fecha como *12/12/2020*, en vez de tener que copiar las barras, que el mismo `Entry` lo haga por mi... yo solo copiaría *12122020*, y el `Entry` fuera capaz de dejarlo con el formato *dd/mm/yyyy*..

Lo mismo con los números de teléfono... imagina que quisiera un formato *(099)-333-78-78*... Solamente ingresaríamos *0993337878* en vez de los paréntesis y los guiones, pero el `Entry` te mostraría el formato como tal lo deseas. Al momento de guardarlo en una `bd`, se guardaría con el formato en sí.

Estuve buscado en la web a ver si conseguía ejemplos pero no tuve suerte... No sé si la propiedad Show permite hacer esto, estuve buscando pero no conseguí nada (o busqué mal jajaja)

Saludos y Gracias

Comment: ¿Quieres que al digitar 12122020 se te agregen las barras o al copiar y pegar 12122020 en el entry se te agregen las barras?

Comment: al principio solamente pensé al momento de digitar la fecha, pero no había pensado en la opción de pegar..

Comment: Puedo responderte al digitar la fecha si quieres, al pegar sinceramente no tengo idea, jajajaja

Comment: jajajaja claro amigo ayúdame con eso y después le buscamos la solución al pegar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas usar la función `bind` en el `Entry` para registrar cada vez que presionen una tecla y ejecute una función en este caso `cuandoEscriba`, y al final yo utilizo otra vez la función `bind` para que ***NO*** se ejecute la funcion `cuandoEscriba` al borrar los caracteres

Explicación breve de la función `cuandoEscriba`:

Primero me fijo si el carácter ingresado es un numero, con la función `isdigit()` luego si es un dígito cuento la cantidad de letras que hay en el `Entry`, si es igual a 2 agrego "/" al texto, y si es igual a 5 agrego otro "/"

P: ¿por que 5 caracteres y no 4?

R: por que hay que contar el caracter "/" agregado previamente

Luego si el carácter ingresado en el `Entry` no es un dígito retorno `"break"`para que no escriba nada.

Espero que te sirva, si necesitas una explicación mas detallada o no se da a entender algo me avisas, saludos!.

```
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk

ventana = Tk()

entryFecha = tk.Entry(ventana)
entryFecha.place(x=30,y=30)

def cuandoEscriba(event):
    if event.char.isdigit():
        texto = entryFecha.get()
        letras = 0
        for i in texto:
            letras +=1

        if letras == 2:
            entryFecha.insert(2,"/")
        elif letras == 5:
            entryFecha.insert(5,"/")
    else:
        return "break"

entryFecha.bind("<Key>", cuandoEscriba)
entryFecha.bind("<BackSpace>", lambda _:entryFecha.delete(tk.END))

ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Franco

Ayudado con tu aporte que me hiciste, aquí dejo el complemento con el ingreso de un número de teléfono con el formato (999)-999-99-99 ... Muchas gracias

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


def escribaFecha(event):
    if event.char.isdigit():
        texto = entryFecha.get()
        letras = 0
        for i in texto:
            letras +=1
        if letras == 2:
            entryFecha.insert(2,"/")
        elif letras == 5:
            entryFecha.insert(5,"/")
    else:
        return "break"

def escribaTelefono(event):
    if event.char.isdigit():
        texto = entryTelefono.get()
        letras = 0
        for i in texto:
            letras +=1                                  
        if len(texto) == 0:                             
            entryTelefono.insert(0,"(")
        if letras == 4:     
            entryTelefono.insert(4,")-")
        elif letras == 9:
            entryTelefono.insert(9,"-")
        elif letras == 12:
            entryTelefono.insert(12,"-")
    else:
        return "break"

ventana = Tk()

Label(ventana, text ='Fecha:').grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 10, padx = 10)
entryFecha = tk.Entry(ventana)
entryFecha.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 10, padx = 10)

Label(ventana, text ='Teléfono:').grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 10, padx = 10)
entryTelefono = tk.Entry(ventana)
entryTelefono.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 10, padx = 10)


entryFecha.bind("<Key>", escribaFecha)
entryFecha.bind("<BackSpace>", lambda _:entryFecha.delete(tk.END))

entryTelefono.bind("<Key>", escribaTelefono)
entryTelefono.bind("<BackSpace>", lambda _:entryTelefono.delete(tk.END))

ventana.mainloop()
```