# ¿Se le puede poner un formato a los Entry en Pyhton?

Tags: python, tkinter

Muy buenas me gustaría saber si a los Entry se le puede poner un formato, como por ejemplo: desea que un Entry tenga un formato de MM/AAAA ya que ese Entry el usuario debe ingresar la fecha de vencimiento de una tarjeta de crédito

Comment: Randy.. verifica esta pregunta que hice ya un tiempo, y muestra la respuesta a lo que buscas  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/337050/dar-formato-de-fecha-a-un-entry-en-python/337117#337117

Comment: Ok muchas gracias por el comentarios

Comment: Aca hay una opcion piola y sencilla. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/337050/dar-formato-de-fecha-a-un-entry-en-python